# Binding a click event in my JavaScript module

Tags: javascript

Since I started structuring my JavaScript as a [module pattern](https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/), some of my click events no longer work. Since other parts of my JavaScript add HTML to the DOM, I need to use `$('body').on('click')` for a button.

This is what my module currently looks like:

```
var s,
MyApp = {    

  settings: {
    fooButton: $(".foo-button"),
    barButton: $(".bar-button")
  },    

  init: function() {
    s = this.settings;
    this.bindEvents();
  },    

  bindEvents: function() {
    // this works
    s.fooButton.on("click", function() {
      MyApp.clickButton("foo");
    });    

    // this does NOT work
    $('body').on('click', s.barButton, function (event) {
      MyApp.clickButton("bar");
    });
  },    

  clickButton: function(button) {
    console.log("You clicked " + button)
  }    

};
```

The first click event is working, the second isn't. How can I bind and event for an element that was created by JavaScript code?

Comment: try `$('body').on('click', s.barButton.attr("id"), function (event){...` instead.

Comment: Since you have a reference to the object that was created (ie, s.fooButton or s.barButton) there is no need to use `$('body').on('click', 'selector', ...)`.  You can simply use `s.fooButton.on("click", function...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument for your handler when the event is delegated  is expected to be a **string**.

In your case it is a **jQuery Object**.
That is the root cause your click event is not working.

Change

```
barButton: $(".bar-button")
```

to

```
barButton: ".bar-button"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating the element in JS, you have to bind the event AFTER the element is created.

So put the binding event in a function, then call that function after your JS code has created the element.  :)

Answer (score 0):

When using `.on()` for event delegation, the second parameter *has to be a string*. Passing anything else won't work.

http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data